# Elasticsearch _default_ mapping via API

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch

i make this call to map by default, *all* datatypes as strings-

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_default_/_mapping' -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                        "match": "*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                }
            ]
        }
   } 
}
'
```

The mapping does not work, so i make this call to verify-

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_mapping'
{
    "logstash-2014.02.05": {
        "_default_": {
            "properties": {}
        }
}
```

Why is the properties part empty?

Comment: is your put correct? I see ```_default_``` is that a typo or is that what you actually PUT, that feels like it should be ```_default```

Comment: i tried both. It [is supposed to be](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-mapper.html#_dynamic_default_mappings) `_default_`.

Comment: that just feels wrong, but you are totally right

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the `mappings` key from your PUT request. You only specify `mappings` when you are creating an index, not when updating mappings.